# custom shiro filter for rest api

Tags: rest, filter, shiro

I have a old rest filter. Can the following be ported to shiro.ini? Or, is it possible to initialize/configure a filter in shiro.ini and extend it in java with `doFilter()`? It looks like there are some strange things going on with error handling and a "shiro bug". I'm not looking for someone to write my code, but a hint where to look would be helpful. Thank you.

UPDATE: MyRestFilter class:

```
@Override
    @SneakyThrows(Throwable.class)
    public void doFilter(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, 
            HttpSession httpSession, final FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        debugRequest(request);
        List<String> sessionIds = Servlets.getRequestQueryStringMap(request).get(SESSION_ID);
        String sessionId = sessionIds == null? null : Iterables.getOnlyElement(sessionIds);
        String sessionIdHeader = request.getHeader(SESSION_ID_HEADER);
        if(sessionId == null)
        {
            sessionId = sessionIdHeader;
        }
        ThreadContext.unbindSubject();
        ThreadContext.bind(securityManager);
        if(sessionId != null)
        {
            // strip out host / instance ID from the session
            sessionId = sessionId.replaceFirst("\\.[\\w_\\-+]+$", "");
            Subject subject = new Subject.Builder().sessionId(sessionId).buildSubject();
            Session session = subject.getSession(false);
            if(session != null)
            {
                session.touch();   // this should not be necessary, but due to Shiro bug, it is
                StatefulUtil.pingStateful(session);
            }
            if(subject.getPrincipal() == null)
            {
                response.sendError(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized API Call");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    subject.execute(() ->
                    {
                        SharedWebstats webStats = Beans.getReference(SharedWebstats.class);
                        webStats.webStats("mobile");

                        if (chain != null)
                        {
                            chain.doFilter(request, response);
                        }
                        return null;
                    });
                }
                catch(ExecutionException e)
                {
                    // unwrap Shiro's ExecutionException, interferes
                    // with global exceptino handling mechanisms
                    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                    if (cause != null)
                    {
                        throw cause;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {            
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        ThreadContext.unbindSecurityManager();
    }
```

//MyRestFilter also contains an init() which contains the real problem: how to  set  a session timeout that applies to the /api/ url only? (note, many of these SecurityManagerFactories are deprecated which is why I have to rewrite this).

```
@Override
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        
        //securityManager = new WebIniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:META-INF/shiro.ini").createInstance();
        securityManager = WebIniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:META-INF/shiro.ini").createInstance();
        int sessionTimeout = WebXml.INSTANCE.getSessionTimeout();
        DefaultSecurityManager dsm = (DefaultSecurityManager)securityManager;
        DefaultSessionManager sm = (DefaultSessionManager)dsm.getSessionManager();
        sm.setGlobalSessionTimeout(sessionTimeout * 60 * 1000);
        realmCache.putAll(securityManager);
        ssse.addSessionListeners(sm.getSessionListeners());
    }
                
    private org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager;
    private @Inject RealmCacheHolder realmCache;
    private @Inject ShiroSessionScopeExtension ssse;
```

Here is some configuration. Currently I have:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.dependencyfromhell.shiro.ee.filters.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>shiroConfigLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/shiro.ini</param-value>
    </context-param>
        
    <!-- Security - Enforce Filter Ordering -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyRestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern/>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I'd like to have something like this.

```
# rest support
rest = MyRestFilter

#Rest api
/api/* = MyRestFilter
```

Could I configure MyRestFilter in shiro.ini for the session timeout, but then have a MyRestFilter class with the doFilter method? Thanks.

Comment: At first glance, I would say yes, it can be converted to Shiro's configuration.

Most of this logic is handled automatically for you by the `ShiroFilter`, it's possible this filter is not setup correctly or not getting processed before your servlet.

That said, I'm guessing there was a reason that sent you down this path.  How are you currently configuring Shiro?  Maybe create a simple standalone example? (replacing your `Beans.getRefernce()` with a log statement or something)

Comment: I inherited a code nightmare lol. I'm trying to get up to speed with shiro though. Updated with some configuration. Please let me know if I can provide anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `init()` method looks to be the source of your problems.

You *basically* have two instances of Shiro configured. One from the `ShiroFilter` in your `web.xml` and another in your custom filter's `init()` method.

I'm guessing this was a workaround to inject your `RealmCacheHolder` and `ShiroSessionScopeExtension`, but it's unclear how they are used.

You can bootstrap Shiro using an IoC framework. (Shiro has direct support for Guice and Spring), if you are using CDI (or something else), it can still be done, but it would require some custom code (likely similar to what you have).

You would implement a `WebEnvironment` and set the `shiroEnvironmentClass` filter context param with its classname.

You might want to hit up the [Shiro User list](https://shiro.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) if want to get a little deeper into the `WebEnvironment` options.

Comment: A good start to a roadmap, which is exactly what I wanted. Thank you.